# How to enhance the speed of my C++ program in reading delimited text files?

Tags: c++, c#-4.0

I show you C# and C++ code that execute the same job: to read the same text file delimited by “|” and save  with “#” delimited text.

When I execute  C++ program, the time elapsed is 169 seconds.

UPDATE 1: Thanks to Seth (compilation with: cl /EHsc /Ox /Ob2 /Oi) and GWW for changing the positions of string s outside the loops, the elapsed time was reduced to 53 seconds. I updated the code also.

UPDATE 2: Do you have any other suggestion to enhace the C++ code?

When I execute the C# program, the elapsed time is 34 seconds!

The question is, how can I enhance the speed of C++ comparing with the C# one?

C++ Program:

```
int main ()
{
    Timer t;
    cout << t.ShowStart() << endl;

    ifstream input("in.txt");
    ofstream output("out.txt", ios::out);
    char const row_delim = '\n';
    char const field_delim = '|';
    string s1, s2;

    while (input)
    {
        if (!getline( input, s1, row_delim ))
            break;
        istringstream iss(s1);
        while (iss)
        {
            if (!getline(iss, s2, field_delim ))
                break;
            output << s2 << "#";
        }
        output << "\n";
    }

    t.Stop();
    cout << t.ShowEnd() << endl;
    cout << "Executed in: " << t.ElapsedSeconds() << " seconds." << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

C# program:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        long i;
        Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
        Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now);
        sw.Start();
        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("in.txt", Encoding.Default);
        StreamWriter wr = new StreamWriter("out.txt", false, Encoding.Default);
        object[] cols = new object[0];  // allocates more elements automatically when filling
        string line;
        while (!string.Equals(line = sr.ReadLine(), null)) // Fastest way
        {
        cols = line.Split('|');  // Faster than using a List<>
        foreach (object col in cols)
            wr.Write(col + "#");
        wr.WriteLine();
        }
        sw.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine("Conteo tomó {0} secs", sw.Elapsed);
        Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now);
    }
```

## UPDATE 3:

Well, I must say I am very happy for the help received and because the answer to my question has been satisfied.

I changed the text of the question a little to be more specific, and I tested the solutions that kindly raised Molbdlino and Bo Persson.

Keeping Seth indications for the compile command (i.e. cl /EHsc /Ox /Ob2 /Oi pgm.cpp):

Bo Persson's solution took 18 seconds on average to complete the execution, really a good one taking in account that the code is near to what I like).

Molbdlino solution took 6 seconds on average, really amazing!! (thanks to Constantine also).

Never too late to learn, and I learned valuable things with my question.

My best regards.

Comment: First of all, what optimisation settings are you using?

Comment: Obligatory, regardless of code: did you compare with all optimizations enabled?

Comment: One easy optimization is to put your `string s;` declaration outside of the loop to prevent constant new / delete calls.  Furthermore, I would also rename the second nested `string s;` to `string s2;` or something like that and also move its definition out of the loops.

Comment: `char const row_delim = '\n\r'` is that even legal, having a `char` hold two `char`s?

Comment: Stream can be slow. You could try use C style I/O if the input is huge.

Comment: I am not c++ expert but what is the `Timer` object that you are using, maybe you should use `QueuePerformanceCounter` instead because that is what the `Stopwatch` in C# uses.

Comment: Ziyao, I am trying to avoid the use of C. Google indicates that C++ is the fastest programming language.

Comment: Lol. C IO is just as much a part of C++ as STL streams are.

Comment: Seth, I am using VC++ 2010 and compilation was:  cl /EHsc pgm.cpp

Comment: Try adding `/Ox /Ob2 /Oi` to your command line

Comment: @Tristan: There's no point in measuring speed if you don't optimize for speed.

Comment: @Seth: ’'\n\r'` is a multi-character character constant.  It's perfectly legal, but questionably useful; the value is implementation-defined.  It almost certainly doesn't do what Tristan thinks it does.

Comment: GMan, the same ways as with my C# program, I am using standard C++ coding and I suppose they are optimal. I also feel that my C++ program is not so complicated.

Comment: @Keith in implementations where a `char` is one byte, I assume it does what my compiler said it does and `warning : truncation of constant value`. Is that correct? And thanks for answering my question.

Comment: Seth, trying with /Ox /Ob2 /Oi  the elapsed time was 67 seconds now!! nothing bad. Many thanks.

Comment: Jalal, thanks for your suggestion. I made sure that the management of timers are uniform in C++ and C#; the elapsed time is only the difference between the start time and the end time of the files processing.

Comment: @Seth: A char is one byte by definition (i.e., the definition of the word "byte"). Don't worry about the specific warning; just don't use multiple-character character constants.  Whatever problem you're trying to solve, they (almost certainly) aren't the solution.

Comment: @Keith I'm not using multiple-character constants, he is, and I'm not trying to solve a problem with them. I just want to know how it's possible to store more than 1 byte in a 1 byte structure (`\n\r` is two characters and therefore 2 bytes), and why this is "implementation-defined" rather than "impossible".

Comment: @Seth: Sorry, lost track of names.  The value is implementation-defined because the language says it is.  (In C, it's of type int; I'm not sure about C++.)

Comment: @Keith ah, I see. I didn't know character constants were made to be able to fit into something other than a `char`. And I think it's `int` for C++ too, because it converts to `int` in my compiler and warns of truncation. Actually come to think of it, my compiler is MSVC++ which probably means converting to `int` is not standard... Anyway, thanks again.

Comment: I don't understand why this post was down voted. I found the question and solution to be extremely helpful and informative.

Comment: @Seth: Ok, I just checked the C++ standard.  In C, an ordinary character literal like `'x'` or `'\n'` is of type int; in C++ it's of type char.  A character literal with more than one character, such as `'xy'` or `'\r\n'`, is of type int in both languages, and has an implementation-defined value.  I think that some pre-standard C compilers supported this syntax (so the committee didn't want to break existing code), but with inconsistent semantics (so they couldn't define the value).  It's best avoided, especially in new code.  (And of course `'xy'` and `"xy"` are very different things.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As Constantine suggests, read large chunks at a time using `read`.

I cut the time from ~25s to ~3s on a 129M file with 5M "entries" (26 bytes each) in 100,000 lines.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

int main ()
{
  ifstream input("in.txt");
  ofstream output("out.txt", ios::out);

  const size_t size = 512 * 1024;
  char buffer[size];

  while (input) {
    input.read(buffer, size);
    size_t readBytes = input.gcount();
    replace(buffer, buffer+readBytes, '|', '#');
    output.write(buffer, readBytes);
  }
  input.close();
  output.close();

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

How about this for the central loop

```
while (getline( input, s1, row_delim ))
{
    for (string::iterator c = s1.begin(); c != s1.end(); ++c)
        if (*c == field_delim)
            *c = '#';

    output << s1 << '\n';
}
```

Comment: Your inner loop can be changed to `std::replace(s1.begin(), s1.end(), field_delim, '#');`

Comment: Yeah, that would make it even shorter, but probably not affect the performance.

Comment: Yes, it just implements the same loop in a template. I think it's worth it just to make the code clearer and more concise.

Answer (score 2):

It seems to me that Your slow part is within `getline`. I don't have precise documentation which would support my idea, but it's how it feels for me. You should try using `read` instead. Because `getline` has the delimiter, so it need to check every symbol whether it has found the delimiter symbol, so that looks like multiple `in` operations, so Your program accesses a symbol in a file, then write it to the memory of your program, in other words, the time consumed on disk head movement. But if You use `read` function, You will copy the block of symbols and then work with them within program's memory, that may reduce time consuming.

PS again, I don't have documentation about `getline` and how it works, but I'm sure about `read`, hope it is helpful.

Comment: Constantine, It's not your problem, but I'm frustrated to know that I have to work hard to improve the speed of my C++ program, approaching more to C; while I feel my C# program is laughing at the situation ..

Comment: Tristan, you need some sleep if you feel your programs are laughing. And don't blame C++ for yourself being an un-knowledgeable C++ programmer. You didn't even compile with optimisations; that speaks volumes.

Comment: Seth, please do not get me wrong and I apologies to Constantine as well, the thing is that to get a C++ faster than C# I've always had to work hard on C++ to achieve reach and sometimes exceed the performance of C# programs, at least using the Windows operating system. I appreciate the tuning options you kindly indicated which lowered the times, but still does not exceed the speed of C# in my case and that intrigues me greatly.

Comment: Constantine, I am in the dilemma that using read, I'll lose the functionality offered by getline for the separators, and it is supposed that getline should be optimized to process large volumes of information. Don't believe so?

Comment: Tristan, my idea is to process all the data to program memory, so you could access it directly. In other words instead of `getline` I suggest you using `read` and then using `string` methods like `find_first_of("|\n\r\0")` - basically operations are all the same, but your disk head will move shorter distance, thus time consumption will be reduced

Answer (score 1):

If you know the max line length you can your [stdio+fgets](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/fgets/) and null terminated strings, it will rock.

For c# if it will fit in memory (probably not if it takes 34 sec) I'd be curious to see how `IO.File.WriteAllText("out.txt",IO.File.ReadAllText("in.txt").Replace("|","#"));` performs!

Comment: FastAI, I tested with the C# solution you kindly indicated and I get an OutOfMemoryException. The in.txt files has 6.5 million records.

Comment: DARN! I figured that would be the case. Few things are as fun as reducing a whole method to a one liner, but I guess if the one liner sucks like mine did, that kind of takes the fun away, doesn't it ;-)

Comment: Regarding C++ vs. C and null strings... It has been forever since I've tried it but can't you just use the C lib in the link right in a C++ program? I remember using null-term lib functions in MS Visual C++ 1.0... can you tell I'm rusty? So I might be wrong about that.

Comment: ...Unless you just want to tune istringstream? It might just be that its implementation is lacking. In both programs, you're doing more parsing than you need to, unless you need to skip delimiters in quotes or double/escaped delimiters, but then, you'll probably need to be doing more parsing, unless isstringstrem does that for you: in which case it's not a fair test, as .net's .Split method won't do that for you. If you don't need that, I'd just implement a replace in both languages. BTW I didn't see the point of the 3 downvotes. Kind of a non-reusable question but not against the faq.

Comment: C++ interested me since I read this interview with Herb Sutter http://www.theregister.co.uk/2011/06/11/herb_sutter_next_c_plus_plus/page2.html
 and this one: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cross-platform/BenchmarkCppVsDotNet.aspx
Curently I was assigned to do programs to load millions of records from flat files into a database for purposes of reconciliation of old data between disparate systems, and I am looking for the appropriate programming language.  I need to write programs quickly, with a huge facility and, with good response times.

Answer (score 0):

I'd be really surprised if this beat @molbdnilo's version, but it's probably the second fastest, and (I would posit) the simplest and cleanest:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <algorithm>

int main() {
    std::ifstream in("in.txt");
    std::ostringstream buffer;
    buffer << in.rdbuf();
    std::string s(buffer.str());
    std::replace(s.begin(), s.end(), '|', '#');
    std::ofstream out("out.txt");
    out << s;
    return 0;
}
```

Based on past experience with this method, I'd expect it to be no worse than half the speed of what @molbdnilo posted -- which should still be around triple the speed of your C# version, and over ten times as fast as your original version in C++. [Edit: I just wrote a file generator, and on a file a little over 100 megabytes, it's even closer than I expected -- I'm getting 4.4 seconds, versus 3.5 for @molbdnilo's code.] The combination of reasonable speed with really short, simple code is often quite a decent trade-off. Of course, that's all predicated on your having enough physical RAM to hold the entire file content in memory, but that's generally a fairly safe assumption these days.

Comment: Jerry, I tested the program and the time elapsed is 29 on average. Regards.

Comment: @Tristan: did you compile with optimization turned off again?

Comment: Jerry, I restarted my machine, recompiled again with cl /EHsc /Ox /Ob2 /Oi, and executed the program 5 times, the results in seconds were: 15, 39, 34, 36 and 39.

Comment: Jerry, by the way, I am processing more than 500MB (6.5 millions records).

Comment: @Tristan: The problem I see isn't much with the overall time as with the variation -- while *some* variation is inevitable, 2.5:1 (or so) seems pretty excessive. The code can clearly do the job in 15 seconds (and maybe less), so the question is whether your timing means much when the rest of the system is routinely providing the data so much more slowly than the code can do its job.

Comment: Jerry, if you agree, I can send you the code to your email address.

Comment: @Tristan: sorry, but I don't give out my email publicly anymore.

Comment: Jerry, I attempted to post the code in your blog (Reading files - march 2011), but it seems I need an authorization.

Comment: @JerryCoffin let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2638/discussion-between-tristan-and-jerry-coffin)