# c++ text file reading performance

Tags: c#, c++, c, file-io, large-files

I'm trying to migrate a c# program to c++.
The c# program reads a 1~5 gb sized text file line by line and does some analysis on each line.
The c# code is like below.

```
using (var f = File.OpenRead(fname))
using (var reader = new StreamReader(f))
    while (!reader.EndOfStream) {
        var line = reader.ReadLine();
        // do some analysis
    }
```

For a given 1.6 gb file with 7 million lines, this code takes about 18 seconds.

The c++ code I wrote first to migrate is like below

```
ifstream f(fname);
string line;    
while (getline(f, line)) {
    // do some analysis
}
```

The c++ code above takes about 420 seconds. The second c++ code I wrote is like below.

```
ifstream f(fname);
char line[2000];
while (f.getline(line, 2000)) {
    // do some analysis
}
```

The c++ above takes about 85 seconds.

The last code I tried is c code, like below.

```
FILE *file = fopen ( fname, "r" );
char line[2000];
while (fgets(line, 2000, file) != NULL ) {
    // do some analysis
}
fclose ( file );
```

The c code above takes about 33 seconds.

Both of the last 2 codes, which parse the lines into char[] instead of string, need about 30 seconds more to convert char[] to string.

Is there a way to improve the performance of c/c++ code to read a text file line by line to match the c# performance?
(Added : I'm using windows 7 64 bit OS with VC++ 10.0, x64)

Comment: Your question is similar to this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7102087/how-to-enhance-the-speed-of-my-c-program-in-reading-delimited-text-files/7102179#7102179

Comment: An interesting question would be: how is C# doing it? That will give you some info into what optimizations they used and probably suggest a few.

Answer (score 9):

One of the best ways to increase file reading performance is to use memory mapped files (`mmap()` on Unix, `CreateFileMapping()` etc on Windows). Then your file appears in memory as one flat chunk of bytes, and you can read it much faster than doing buffered I/O.

For a file larger than a gigabyte or so, you will want to be using a 64-bit OS (with a 64-bit process). I've done this to process a 30 GB file in Python with excellent results.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest two things:

Use `f.rdbuf()->pubsetbuf(...)` to set a bigger read buffer. I've noticed some really significant increases in fstream performance when using larger buffer sizes.

Instead of `getline(...)` use `read(...)` to read larger blocks of data and parse them manually.

Answer (score 0):

Compile with optimizations. C++ has quite some theoretical overhead that the optimizer will remove. E.g. many simple string methods will be inlined. That's probably why your `char[2000]` version is faster.